# How to include SpecFlow .html report in CruiseControl BuildReport?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, specflow

all.

How to include SpecFlow .html report in CruiseControl BuildReport?
Is exists ready to use solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [File Merge Task](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/File+Merge+Task), you can specify an action of "Copy."  This will copy the html file to the artifacts folder for that build.  Then modify the dashboard config to include a link to the html file.

Comment: Is this working solution in your company or concept as it may work?

Comment: I wrote xslt and include part of SpecFlow html report in CC.Net build log.

Comment: We use the File Merge task to copy output from Nitriq, as it currently only produces html reports.